# How can I calculate the probability of event P(A|B|C)?ı

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I need to calculate the conditional probability of three events to get a result for P(A|B|C). How can I do that?

Comment: The notation P(A|B|C) isn't meaningful: you can't have multiple "|" ("given that" or "conditional on") symbols.  What probability are you trying to calculate?  Is it the probability of the event "A and B and C"?  That's denoted Pr[A, B, C] or Pr[A and B and C].  Or perhaps you are interested in Pr[A | B, C], which is the probability of A conditional on B and C?